# Getting 404 error when accessing a php file externally

Tags: php, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a cloud server running Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0 web server on which I want to install a contact form to email details. I have found a template using PHP and installed PHP 7.1.24 so that the contact form works when I access the form on the cloud server using http://localhost/phpmailer/examples/contactform.php. I can also access PHP info using http://localhost/phpinfo.php. This file is installed at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php.

However, if I try to access either PHP file externally using http://websitename/phpinfo.php or http://websitename/phpmailer/examples/contactform.php I get a 404 error. I can externally access an HTML file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot OK.

What do I need to do in order to be able to access the PHP file externally?

Comment: You need to review site bindings first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: The default binding as shown in IIS Manager is Type:http, Port:80, IP Address *. Host Name and Binding Information are empty. What do I need to change to address my problem?

Comment: Then for a cloud server, there are at least two firewalls you need to configure (Windows Firewall on the server itself, and the cloud firewall for example) so that HTTP requests at TCP port 80 can go (inbound traffic in most descriptions).

Comment: The inbound Windows firewall rule World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic In) for local port 80 does not have any properties tab that specifies file extensions, so I can't see why this should affect why I can get an html target but not a php one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Can you use FRT to see what component gives you the 404?

Comment: I have tried to configure failed request tracking on the web server. The Failed Request Log folder  FailReqLogFiles is created but no entries appear in it after 404 errors appear, even though a rule is created including these failure codes.

Comment: At site level you need to enable FRT or there would be no log at all. If possible, you might also use tools like Wireshark to confirm the 404 error page comes from this server (in case it comes from elsewhere).